# Porting a rails4 app from MRI to JRuby with puma, no luck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails

I'm developing a rails 4.0.0.beta1 app on MRI 2.0.0 and all looks working. I would like to try to run it on JRuby with puma.

```
$ ruby -v
jruby 1.7.3 (1.9.3p385) 2013-02-21 dac429b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406 [darwin-x86_64]
```

I changed my Gemfile this way:

```
if defined?(JRUBY_VERSION)
  gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', :require => false
  gem 'jdbc-mysql'
  gem 'puma'
else
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem 'thin', '1.5.1'
end
```

and I did bundle install (all ok).

When I try to run puma with

```
$ bundle exec puma
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Puma 2.0.1 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9292
NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Application::Railties
```

I tryed to google but I couldn't find any information about the error, someone has an idea how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing the path to the `bundle` executable was laid down when you installed bundler through your MRI environment. What happens when you run something like `jruby -S bundle exec puma`?

Comment: @ChrisMowforth I tryed and I get the same error, do you have any other idea? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found (luckly), I think it's a rails's problem on rc1, to solve it put this in your Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
```

Then you will get another error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Session::EncryptedCookieStore
```

You can solve this changing your 'initializers/session_store.rb' to

```
Foo::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_foo_session'
```

(pay attention at your app's name in the correct place, don't use 'Foo')

Enjoy!